# What is needed to use a newer version of GCC than the platform provides

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I am looking at the potential to use a newer version of GCC (e.g. 5.2) than is provided by some of the platforms that I need to support (GCC 4.1) as I would like to at least have C++11 features, and maybe even some C++14 things. I just provide an executable program, not static or shared libraries that I expect users of the platform to be able to link with.

I was able to compile GCC 5.2 and Boost 1.59 (the only lib with a C++ API I am using currently) and get it working with the so's for those placed alongside the executable and adding $ORIGIN to RPATH on a test system which has 4.4.

But I am unclear on what else I need to do this fully and ensure everything is correct/safe. e.g. I noticed libc, libm, libpthread, etc. are not part of the GCC build, and it still uses the system version, as with many other third party libraries (e.g. zlib, libpng, etc.). Do I need to rebuild and distribute all those to be safe? Is their a standard set of rules to tell?

Also wondering if I should statically link some things and again what the rules are? e.g. just using "-static" fails because it goes looking for a static pthread that I don't have on that system (and I assume other system-provided libraries). Ideally I want to keep the size of my package down.

Answer (score 3):

> But I am unclear on what else I need to do this fully and ensure everything is correct/safe. e.g. I noticed libc, libm, libpthread, etc. are not part of the GCC build, and it still uses the system version, as with many other third party libraries (e.g. zlib, libpng, etc.). Do I need to rebuild and distribute all those to be safe? Is their a standard set of rules to tell?

Run `ldd` on your executables and shared libraries to make sure that it loads `libstdc++` and `libgcc_s` from the correct location, if you link them dynamically. These are the only two dependencies normally required to run your applications built with g++.

Normally, you do not need to provide your own versions of libraries with `C` interface, unless your application requires newer versions with incompatible APIs.

Comment: Is it just the interface that is important and pretty much answers the "do U need to recompile and distribute libx?" question? My concern was that in theory such a library might use C++ internally, compiled against some other GCC and libstdc++ version, and what happens then?

Comment: @FireLancer This is another question on its own. If you happen to link against 3rd-party C++ binary-only libraries, you need to make sure that your application and the 3rd-party library use the same C++ ABI for types present in the library interface. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

Comment: Sorry, maybe i was unclear or confused my self. I did not mean libraries that are externally C++, like boost, I get that they generally need to match the compiler. But what if a library with a C interface used C++ internally? Do I need to carefully check for, rebuild and package those if I use a different GCC to the distro? e.g. in theory one could write libraries similar to zlib using C++.

Comment: @FireLancer If those 3rd-party libraries link to system `libstdc++` and `libgcc_s` you may get away with using your own versions of these, I would need to read up on `stdlibc++` symbol versioning and binary compatibility. However, those 3rd-party libraries may also depend on an older system version of boost library but boost does not maintain a stable ABI between versions. In this case you can try loading the 3rd-party library into a separate linker namespace, but that gets too tricky too quickly.

Comment: @FireLancer I remember now, I had my python modules built with gcc-4.9 and C++11 using boost::python. My modules worked well in python scripts but would fail to load under `ipython`. Turned out ipython uses the system zeromq C++ library which gets loaded on `ipython` start and it pulled in the system `libstdc++`. When my python/C++ modules got loaded `libstdc++` was already there but it did not provide symbols my modules expected and loading would fail. This was solved by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to my versions of `libstdc++` for `ipython` and zeromq seemed happy to use my `libstdc++`.

Answer (score 2):

Recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compilers have a lot of dependencies.

On some distributions, you could ask for them : on Debian or related you might `aptitude build-dep gcc` (provided you have `deb-src:` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`) which would dowload the build dependencies of the system's `gcc` (which might have a lot of common dependencies with the latest [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)).

Otherwise, [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) source code contain a [contrib/download_prerequisites](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-5-branch/contrib/download_prerequisites?view=markup) script which should be handy.

Read carefully the GCC [building procedure](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/). Don't forget to compile it *outside* of the source tree. You might want to pass `--program-suffix=-5-mine` to its `configure`

Of course you'll also need to build all the other software needed to compile (or to cross-compile) your code with the newly built GCC, including [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), and perhaps a C library

Alternatively use a `chroot` (or some container à la [docker](https://www.docker.com/)) to install a newer Linux system...

Comment: I'm guessing the down vote was because you have answered a different question to the one asked. I read the question as "do I need to recompile libc etc with my gcc and distribute them with the application.

Comment: Well I already built GCC as-per their instructions, but that is hardly the only dependency and doesn't detail compatibility concerns if I don't then proceed to rebuild the entire system (which if I could I could / just use a newer distro, but customers want to stay on their current Linux distro versions)

Answer (score 2):

> I noticed libc, libm, libpthread, etc. are not part of the GCC build, and it still uses the system version, as with many other third party libraries (e.g. zlib, libpng, etc.). Do I need to rebuild and distribute all those to be safe?

No. If you build GCC on the system you want to deploy to then the GCC binaries and shared libraries will depend on the system versions of libc, libpthread etc.

If you then use that GCC to compile your software, and deploy the new `libstc++.so.6` alongside your software (using `$ORIGIN` so it will be found), then it will still use the system versions of those libraries. Which is exactly what should happen and what you want to happen. Rebuilding them would achieve nothing and simply mean you have more libraries to deploy alongside your software.

Answer (score 1):

Follow directions to build from source. Revise your question if you face a problem.

Comment: Like I said, I have built GCC from source successfully, but doing so does not include every library on the system naturally, so not sure if that is the entire requirement to get a package I can deploy safely. e.g. for boost it certainly was not, the boost shared objects from the platforms repositories would not even link.

Comment: C libraries need not be rebuilt unless the ABI has changed. C++ libraries must be rebuilt if name mangling convention or ABI changes. Again, try things and report actual problems. Speculating about potential issues isn't productive.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an easier way then compiling GCC yourself. [Unfortunately I figured that out after compiling it from source a number of time :) ]

For example in Ubuntu there is a PPA for precompiled GCC versions which are not there yet in the official repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5
sudo update-alternatives 
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 20
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```